# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on CCHmac

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, exc-bad-access, hmac

i am doing HMAC-SHA256 encoding . Tried but didn't find any solutions.

```
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

- (NSString *)hmacWithKey:(NSString *)key andData:(NSString *)data
{
const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////but on below line of code i am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS//////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

//////////////////////////////////////////////

NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:cHMAC length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

// description converts to hex but puts <> around it and spaces every 4 bytes
NSString *hash = [out description];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
// hash is now a string with just the 40char hash value in it
NSLog(@"%@",hash);
return hash;
}
```

Please tell me whats wrong i am doing here.
Thanks

Comment: What is the error displayed in the debugger?

Comment: it shows nothing . not a single word ,just shows EXS_BAD_ACCESS on this line

Comment: Don't name string variables and arguments "data",that just makes the program harder to understand.

Comment: Look at the inputs to and output from CCHmac with NSLog(), that is the simplest first step to finding the problem. Also without that people on SO trying to help can only guess. Also provide sample inputs so the code can be tried.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding` can return `NULL` if the string contains non-ASCII characters.
Therefore you should check if `cKey == NULL` or `cData == NULL`.

Or better, convert to UTF-8 strings:

```
const char *cKey  = [key UTF8String];
const char *cData = [data UTF8String];
```

Comment: @MuhammadSaadAnsari: What are the input values `key` and `data`? Did you check if `cKey` or `cData` is NULL?

Comment: It amazes me that people come to SO and ask a question and have not even added NSLog statements around the problem.

Comment: @MartinR i was sending null value for Key . Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I ran the OPs code with sample strings with no error so the error must be in the input. Either one or more of the inputs is nil or non-ascii.

Please provide sample input that fails.

BTW, it is not necessary to use char strings, here is an example using NSData:

```
NSData *cKey  = [key  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *cData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *out = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey.bytes, cKey.length, cData.bytes, cData.length, out.mutableBytes);
NSLog(@"out: %@", out);
```